# getCanonicalPath() does not return absolute path on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, java

I'm having an issue fetching the complete path of using getCanonicalPath() inside a spring boot app that I deployed in ec2 .

```
String absolute_path = new
File("../datalake").getCanonicalPath()+"/"+files_path;
absolute_path = absolute_path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
System.out.println(absolute_path);
```

Expected Output :

```
/opt/apache-8/datalake/TestDataset-10001/TestDataSource-10001/Extraction-10027
```

Current Output :

```
/datalake/TestDataset-10001/TestDataSource-10001/Extraction-10027
```

**More Detail**

I have deployed a spring boot web application inside an ec2 instance under
and I'm trying the fetch the path of " data lake " folder in the location

`/opt/apache-8/datalake`

from a war, I deployed under
`/opt/apache-8/webapps/`

I've tried all internet answers I could find, not sure how to approach this, is it a permission issue, I was hoping if someone encountered similar issue

FYI Right now the permission distribution is as follows

> **Jenkins** User/group: Jenkins/Jenkins
>
> **Tomcat, Apache2, SFTP Server**  User/group: ubuntu/ubuntu

I've spent like 2 days on this alone

Comment: Whats the output from `getPath()` or `getAbsolutePath()` and are you shure this is a Ubuntu and not an ec2 issue? Have you tested your code on a "local machine"?

Comment: It looks something like this for getAbsolutePath()
 /../datalake/TestDataset-10001/TestDataSource-10001/Extraction-10029

Comment: And on a local machine?

Comment: I use windows, It displays the full path like :
Z:/WORKPLACE/TaskN/Sub1/Sub2/datalake/TestDataset-10001/TestDataSource-10001/Extraction-10019

Comment: So there you got your answer, its probably a ec2 issue. To be shure you should install WMware player or VirtualBox and install a ubuntu VM in them, since they virtualize in a more propper way!

Comment: Could it be something related to permissions or something, just throwing some ideas around . Or is it something else ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98844/discussion-between-ani-and-matsk).

Comment: I have no idea in how ec2 works as in virtualization/emulation. I know that "Linux Subsystem for Windows" has a lot of flaws in the emulation and both VMware and VirtualBox is much more correct in their virtualization.